# Stopping Exoplayer onSwipe of ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, exoplayer

I am using a `ViewPager` with single fragment instance in which I am showing `Media` files like Images, Videos, Audio.

I have implemented `ExoPlayer` for handling `Video` & `Audio` files. And `Glide` for images.

To avoid the memory leaks I am releasing the `ExoPlayer` object like this in `ItemViewerFragment.java` :

```
 private void releasePlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
            trackSelector = null;
            simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (player == null && currentGalleryModel != null) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (player == null && currentGalleryModel != null) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releasePlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        releasePlayer();
    }
```

And in `onViewCreated()` I am initializing view like this :

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        if (currentGalleryModel.isVideo() || currentGalleryModel.isAudio()) {

            simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            initializePlayer();
        } else if (currentGalleryModel.isImage() || currentGalleryModel.isGif()) {
            simpleExoPlayerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(currentGalleryModel.getFilePath())
                    .placeholder(android.R.color.black)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .into(imageView);

        }
    }
```

I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapeter`. This is the `getItem` method :

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ItemViewerFragment.newInstance(mItems.get(position));
}
```

I am not able to detect the `onPause` of the fragment on first swipe of `Viewpager`. On second swipe `video/audio` files are stopped playing.

In activity I have tried adding `.addOnPageChangeListener` :

```
@Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

     try {
        ((ItemViewerFragment)mAdapter.getItem(mPreviousPos)).imHiddenNow();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPreviousPos = position;
    }
```

And in `ItemViewerFragment.java` :

```
public void imHiddenNow(){
      releasePlayer();
    }
```

Still `video/audio` keeps on playing.

Here is a [Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_er4uRW9U5hX3pfTGJDanhEclU/view?usp=sharing) to the Screencast.

[Demo project GitHub link](https://github.com/nieldeokar/ExoVideoPlayer).

Comment: How are you getting the previous position in the onScrollListener?

Comment: Plus i see the the getItem method is returning a newInstance everytime which may be the cause.

Comment: While initialization I  am storing the current position of the `GalleryModel` which is showing. So suppose I have 30 items in my list and I am displaying 5th. Then `onScroll` the previous position would be 5th and current would be either 4th or 6th depending on which side it has been scrolled.

Comment: The get item looks fishy i am posting an answer with some code try that pageAdapter.

Comment: I am using same fragment so I am returning `newInstance` every time. Do you have any thoughts on how could we improve this ?

Comment: Yes i have posted code for all if you have any questions please revert.

Comment: I have answered my approach below. Have a look @rupesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed an approach of maintaining `HashMap` of fragment objects inside `PagerAdapter`

1. Declare an interface :

```
interface FragmentLifecycle {
    void onPauseFragment()
}
```

2. Implement an interface in Fragment.

```
public void onPauseFragment() {
    if (simpleExoPlayer != null){
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
}
```

3. Store all the fragment objects in a `HashMap<Integer,Fragment>` with there respective positions as a key. Declare hashmap inside `PagerAdapter`. Also declare one getter method for accessing fragment objects from hashmap. e.g.

   ```
   @Override
   public Fragment getItem(int position) {
       ItemViewerFragment fragment = ItemViewerFragment.newInstance(mItems.get(position));
       mFragments.put(position,fragment);
       return fragment;
   }
   ```

   public ItemViewerFragment getMapItem(int position) {
         return mFragments.get(position);
       }
4. In activity where you have declared `viewPager` keep one variable `currentPosition` and implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.
5. Inside `onPageSelected` method,

   ```
       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           if(mAdapter.getMapItem(currentPosition) != null) (mAdapter.getMapItem(currentPosition)).onPauseFragment();
           currentPosition = position;
       }
   ```

Comment: This is an anti-pattern, `getItem()` is NOT called to get a fragment instance by a FragmentPagerAdapter after Android is coming back after process death. The map will inevitably cause NPEs in the future.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit from the future: you should never hold a reference to Fragment instances directly inside a FragmentPagerAdapter, because it can cause crashes after process death.**

Here is the code for the pager adapter:

```
 class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Here is the scroll Listener:

```
  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
          //Stop media here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          //Save your previous position here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
         
        }
    });
```

For the media you can use a for Loop and add all the fragments to the list at once and then use this for efficiency :

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

This will make sure only 3 instances of your fragment are available which is enough.

For using single fragment i would suggest you to do it like this:

```
 public MyFragment() {

}

//This is to send a file to the fragment if you need it.
public static MyFragment newInstance(File file) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("file", file);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

Then in the onCreate of Fragment you can retrieve your file like this:

```
File file;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    file = getArguments().getSerializable("file");
   
}
```

Now add your fragments to pager like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(MyFragment.newInstance(fileList.get(i));
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay I would it it a try. Thanks!

Comment: So suppose if I have 1000 media files. It would create a 1000 fragments ?  `mFragmentList` would be this big ?

Comment: List of models ?

Comment: So yea it will also create a list of fragments but as we changed the offScreenLimit to 3 it will help in maintaining only 3 instances.

Comment: I don't think so since I do not have any `mFragmentList` in my adapter. Every time it would return new instance whenever it goes off the `offscreenLimit`. I would study on this to know the exactly what is happening.

Comment: That's why i posted the code for an adapter with a list in which you simply add all the fragment object and then scroll through them. The viewpager will automatically request for a new instance if it is beyond the offscreen limit.

Comment: I have tried the above sample. The behavior is same just video gets stopped after swiping for 3 times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156449/discussion-between-sarthak-gandhi-and-nilesh-deokar).

Comment: Sometimes It is not recreating a video view after swiping back.

Comment: Hi i have made the changes to the code. Please try it

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the change ?

Comment: take what you have written in onPageScrolled to onPageSelected.

Comment: The whole thing

Comment: Nope the behavior is same.. Video is not stopping on first swipe.

Comment: If you have so many definitely  you will not want to load all the fragments into memory at once. You would like to load and destroy Fragments as the user reads. In this case you will use FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Answer (score 2):

It's been more then a year since I used Exoplayer & I kinda tackled a similar problem. Please note that the APIs have changed a little bit so take the following code just to get an idea on how to implement a potential solution. Please let me know if it doesn't work, I'll look into the APIs further and get back to you.

Coming to the solution:

```
private int mPlayerCurrentPosition;

private int getCurrentPlayerPosition() {
     return mExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

// call this from onPause
private void releaseExoplayer() {
     mPlayerCurrentPosition = getPlayerCurrentPosition();
     mExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
     mExoPlayer.release(); // this will make the player object eligible for GC
}

private void resumePlaybackFromPreviousPosition(int prevPosition) {
    mExoPlayer.seekTo(mPlayerCurrentPosition );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Behavior is same. I want to pause player on first swipe of the `viewPager` it is happening in the second swipe.

Comment: Did you try calling the releaseExoplayer() mentioned in my answer from onPageScrolled and onPageScrollStateChanged callbacks for the viewPager?

Comment: Yes i did.. Even though `onSwipe` current fragment is stopping the player. `onSwipeBack` to same fragment does not resume the Player. I am calling `resumePlaybackFromPreviousPosition` in `onResume` of fragment

Comment: That's probably because you need to reinitialize the player properly. You haven't shared the code you are using for reinitializing the player. Second thing to keep in mind is you need to persist the previous position of the player in onSaveInstance() callback and reread the value in onActivityCreated() or in onCreateView() of the fragment. If you do these things properly, theoretically the problem should be resolved.

Comment: I have shared the detailed demo project github link. If you ever get time just walk over it. I would update after implementing your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: To get the best support from this community, it's always advised to write concise question with all the required code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `onPause` and `onResume` are not called when the fragment visibility changed in ViewPager.
The solution is to add 2 visibility events: `losingVisibility` and `gainVisibility`.

### Why is it a great solution?

Because you keep the framework managing Fragment cache and lifecycle.
We just add the callbacks needed to pause and resume our media in our fragment.

### Step-by-step:

The below code is just an explanation for my code. Check [Step*.java](https://github.com/ericksprengel/udacity-baking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/ericksprengel/android/baking/ui/recipe) classes to see full implementation.

1. Create `losingVisibility` and `gainVisibility` methods in [YourFragment.java](https://github.com/ericksprengel/udacity-baking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/ericksprengel/android/baking/ui/recipe/StepFragment.java#L244):

   ```
   public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

       /**
         * This method is only used by viewpager because the viewpager doesn't call onPause after
         * changing the fragment
         */
       public void losingVisibility() {
           // IMPLEMENT YOUR PAUSE CODE HERE
           savePlayerState();
           releasePlayer();
       }

       /**
         * This method is only used by viewpager because the viewpager doesn't call onPause after
         * changing the fragment
       */
       public void gainVisibility() {
           // IMPLEMENT YOUR RESUME CODE HERE
           loadVideo();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call `losingVisibility` and `gainVisibility` every time a new page is selected (`onPageSelected`) in [YourActivity.java](https://github.com/ericksprengel/udacity-baking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/ericksprengel/android/baking/ui/recipe/StepActivity.java#L70):

   ```
   mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           YourFragment cachedFragmentLeaving = mYourPagerAdapter.getCachedItem(mCurrentItem);
           if (cachedFragmentLeaving != null) {
               cachedFragmentLeaving.losingVisibility();
           }
           mCurrentItem = position;
           YourFragment cachedFragmentEntering = mYourPagerAdapter.getCachedItem(mCurrentItem);
           if (cachedFragmentEntering != null) {
               cachedFragmentEntering.gainVisibility();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
       }
   });
   ```
3. Add `getCachedItem` to [YourPagerAdapter.java](https://github.com/ericksprengel/udacity-baking/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/ericksprengel/android/baking/ui/recipe/StepPagerAdapter.java#L43):

> The 3rd step is adding a method to retrieve cached fragments. To do it we must cache a reference to a fragment created (overriding `instantiateItem`) and release the same reference (overriding `destroyItem`).

```
    public class YourPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

            private SparseArray<YourFragment> mFragmentsHolded = new SparseArray<>();


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Object fragment = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if(fragment instanceof StepFragment) {
                mFragmentsHolded.append(position, (StepFragment) fragment);
            }
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            mFragmentsHolded.delete(position);
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        }

        public YourFragment getCachedItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentsHolded.get(position, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i know its so late but i hope it helps anyone ...
viewPager keeps offscreen fragment started ..
so you have: 
 
prev offscreen fragment (start) -->  visible fragment (working)--> next offscreen fragment (start)

 solution is you can override `Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()` and handle play/pause video..

Comment: `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` even though it is set to 0 still view pager will keep -1 and +1 fragments.

Comment: i have edited my answer because minimum & default offscreen fragments that `setOffscreenPageLimit()` can handle is one  ..`Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()` is the best solution